# Can I use CLang and libstdc++ (emmintrin.h)

Tags: c++, gcc, debian, clang

The following code

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

compiles fine with both g++ and clang

```
g++ test.cpp
clang -I /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include -I /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed -lstdc++ test.cpp
```

where `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/` points to the include files of the libstdc++

However, when I add an additional `#include <emmintrin.h>`

the clang compilations fails with

```
In file included from test.cpp:2:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/emmintrin.h:36:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/xmmintrin.h:36:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/mmintrin.h:46:72: warning: unknown attribute '__artificial__' ignored [-Wunknown-attributes]
extern __inline void __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
                                                                   ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/mmintrin.h:52:72: warning: unknown attribute '__artificial__' ignored [-Wunknown-attributes]
extern __inline void __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))

...

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/xmmintrin.h:120:19: error: use of undeclared identifier '__builtin_ia32_divss'; did you mean '__builtin_ia32_minss'?
return (__m128) __builtin_ia32_divss ((__v4sf)__A, (__v4sf)__B);

...
```

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header, the `xmmintrin.h' is not part of the interface of the standard C++ library and hence I guess it contains Gnu specific stuff.  Can I somehow compile this code using clang?

If not, how can I easily install the clang libc++?
`sudo aptitude install libc++-dev` doesn't find a package (while this does work on Ubuntu 16.04)

I'm using

```
"Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5) // Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
clang version 3.6.0 (trunk 224504) // Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: Does it work if you use the `-stdlib=libstdc++` flag instead of amending the include path like you're doing now?

Comment: Indeed, please do not mess with system directories, the right list of includes is quite tricky, let the compiler handle it (I would have expected it to work by default, without any -I). Normally clang will use gcc's c++ includes, but its own emmintrin.h.

Comment: Compiling the initial version (without the emmintrin.h) with `clang -stdlib=libstdc++  test.cpp` doesn't work (fails to find stdarg.h).  Note that I don't have a libc++ installed right now.  `clang -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null` reports also `ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/bin/../lib/clang/3.6.0/include"`

Comment: @MarcGlisse: I noticed that my installed clang (on Wheezy) does not contain an `emmintrin.h` (check with `dpkg-query -L`) while my installed clang on Ubuntu does contain it (at `/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/lib/clang/3.8.0/include/emmintrin.h`).  
Hence apparently, my installed clang package on Wheezy is incomplete.  I'll investigate this in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my clang installation was incomplete.

After downloading llvm and clang (v3.7.1 since v4.0.1 required gcc4.8 while I only have 4.7) and building it locally  `clang -lstdc++ test.cpp` works fine in both cases.

Comment: If you call it `clang++`, do you ever have to write `-lstdc++`? It should be done automatically.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Correct! `clang++ test.cpp` works also fine.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!